# R is omitting values when replacing column in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am currently having a coding issue in R.  This is my first post here so I hope I am doing this correctly.

I am replacing a column in a dataframe in R with the following code.  North, South, and West all replace fine, but R is not allowing me to substitute East.  It is keeping those points numeric.  What is happening and how can I tweak my code to fix it?  oj$region is a numeric vector that ranges from 2 to 137.

```
oj$region <- replace(oj$region, oj$region >= 2 & oj$region <= 53, "West")
oj$region <- replace(oj$region, oj$region >= 54 & oj$region <= 86, "North")
oj$region <- replace(oj$region, oj$region >= 88 & oj$region <= 111, "East")
oj$region <- replace(oj$region, oj$region >= 112 & oj$region <= 137, "South")
```

As you can see, my code is identical between the all the lines.  I am new to R so if there may be a quirk I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because after the first line, `region` becomes a character column due to **[coercion](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/r-in-a/9781449358204/ch05s08.html)**. Then comparisons like `>` works slightly different than you expect. Here's one example:

```
"88" > "111"
#[1] TRUE
```

vs.

```
88 > 111
#[1] FALSE
```

---

Here are some alternative approaches. **Note that the obtained values could be slightly different.**

```
#DATA
set.seed(42)
oj = data.frame(region = sample(2:137), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**1**

```
oj$region2 <- replace(oj$region, oj$region >= 2 & oj$region <= 53, "West")
oj$region2 <- replace(oj$region2, oj$region >= 54 & oj$region <= 86, "North")
oj$region2 <- replace(oj$region2, oj$region >= 88 & oj$region <= 111, "East")
oj$region2 <- replace(oj$region2, oj$region >= 112 & oj$region <= 137, "South")
```

**2**

[LMunyan's Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48408651/7128934)

**3**

```
oj$region4 = as.character(factor(cut(x = oj$region,
                                     breaks = c(0, 53, 86, 111, 137)),
                                 labels = c("West", "North", "East", "South")))
```

Comment: It looks like the numeric in `>=` or `<=` are being converted to character and then the strings are being compared. Note from `?"<="`: `"Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic within the strings using the collating sequence of the locale in use..."`

Comment: Also another option (but a terrible one) would be to use the original code but to wrap the comparisons in `as.numeric()`

Answer (score 1):

You could also try something like this:

```
oj$region <- ifelse(oj$region >=2 & oj$region <= 53, "West", 
       ifelse(oj$region >=54 & oj$region <=86, "North",
       ifelse(oj$region >= 88 & oj$region <=111, "East", "South")))
```